# Javascript error: “missing ) after argument list”

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. Please help me. It gives the error above when I try to run the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Mark Snier</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

   <script type="text/javascript">
 function init() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var raf;
  var animatie = window.requestAnimationFrame;
  var ball = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  vx: 5,
  vy: 2,
  radius: 25,
  color: 'red',
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();

    for (var h = 0; h < 100; h++) {
      ctx.fillRect (canvas.width-10, w, 10, 10);
      w += 11
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      ctx.fillRect (0, x, 10, 10);
      x += 11
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
      ctx.fillRect (y, canvas.height-10, 10, 10);
      y += 11
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      ctx.fillRect (z, 0, 10, 10);
      z += 11
    };
  };
 }
 ball.draw();       

 function draw() {
   if (ball.y+ball.vy > canvas.height || ball.y+ball.vy < 0) {
      ball.vy = -ball.vy;
   }
   if (ball.x+ball.vx > canvas.width || ball.x+ball.vx < 0) {
      ball.vx = -ball.vx;
   }
   ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var x = 0
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        ctx.fillRect (0, x, 10, 10);
        x += 11
      }
      ball.draw();
      ball.x += ball.vx;
      ball.y += ball.vy;
      raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
   }
   ball.draw();
   refresh();
   function refresh() {
      draw()
      refresh()
   }    
 }
 </script>

 </head>

   <body onload="init()">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="802" height="395"></canvas>

   </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: If you format your code properly I bet the error would be much easier to find.

Comment: *At least* tell us which line causes the error!

Comment: Change function refresh() {
       draw()
       refresh()
   } to function refresh() {
       draw()
       refresh();
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you forgot close any loop or function. In your case,  you have an `;` within your object

```
function init() { 
   var ball = {
      ...
      draw: function() {    
         ...
      }// <-- Remove ; here
   };
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the problem. The code is poorly formatted, but the for loop is being closed properly.

Comment: U sure? I see in the code It has posted that `for` loop is not closed properly and It has a `;` within its ball object. Take a look

Comment: Yes, I'm sure - you even formatted the code above, and there you can see that the for loop is closed :-) The closing bracket has an extra semicolon, but that's getting ignored. The problem is the semicolon after the function because it is inside the object where it causes the syntax error. I've extended my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: The problem is the semicolon inside ball object and the `for` loop not closed

Comment: In addition to, another error is that  `ball.draw();` is being called out of `init()` method and ball object is defined inside `init()` method ;)

Comment: OK, please help me understand this. Because I don't get it... Let's talk about line numbers, ok? If you look at the original post, in line 45 the for loop gets closed, in line 46 the ball.draw function gets closed, in line 47 the ball object gets closed. In line 67 the draw function gets closed (which starts at line 50). In line 75 the refresh function gets closed, and in line 77 the init function gets closed. I don't see any missing closing brackets... Please help me understand what you want to close here.

Comment: You're right my fault, Sorry. I haven't seen that  `init()` function is closed at the end of the script. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which tool gave you this weird error message, but when you open the page in Chrome, it clearly tells you that

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in line 46
```

and if you open your code in a proper editor, e.g. Webstorm, it indicates the same error.

There you define an object `ball` containing a function `draw`, and because it's defined inside the object, it must not be terminated with `;`. If you remove the semicolon, a red ball appears on the page. There are more errors, but this should get you started. This is the correct code:

```
var ball = {
  // ...
  draw: function() {
    // ...
   for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
     ctx.fillRect (z, 0, 10, 10);
     z += 11
   } // <-- you should remove the semicolon you have here - it is unneccessary but is ignored and does not cause problems
 }   // <-- you must remove the semicolon you have here 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you new to javascript? seems like you are missing some of ; and extra ; in certain areas,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var raf;
        var animatie = window.requestAnimationFrame;
        var ball = {
            x: 100,
            y: 100,
            vx: 5,
            vy: 2,
            radius: 25,
            color: 'red',
            draw: function () {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                ctx.fill();

                for (var h = 0; h < 100; h++) {
                    ctx.fillRect(canvas.width - 10, w, 10, 10);
                    w += 11;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    ctx.fillRect(0, x, 10, 10);
                    x += 11;
                }
                for (var k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
                    ctx.fillRect(y, canvas.height - 10, 10, 10);
                    y += 11;
                }
                for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                    ctx.fillRect(z, 0, 10, 10);
                    z += 11;
                }
            }
        }
        ball.draw();

        function draw() {
            if (ball.y + ball.vy > canvas.height || ball.y + ball.vy < 0) {
                ball.vy = -ball.vy;
            }
            if (ball.x + ball.vx > canvas.width || ball.x + ball.vx < 0) {
                ball.vx = -ball.vx;
            }
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var x = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                ctx.fillRect(0, x, 10, 10);
                x += 11;
            }
            ball.draw();
            ball.x += ball.vx;
            ball.y += ball.vy;
            raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }

        ball.draw();
        refresh();

        function refresh() {
            draw();
            refresh();
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Should be working already, I used Visual studio to double check, seems weird when they did not tell me I'm was missing out some ;